Why data is not synchronized between two servers?
CentOS 9
On both servers (prod-nfs-1.corp.domain.local and prod-nfs-2.corp.domain.local) installed: dnf --enablerepo=highavailability -y install pacemaker pcs
The following configuration is performed:
On each server, an LVM volume of 800 GB with the xfs file system is created
The following resources are then created
pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.10.1.210 cidr_netmask=32 op monitor interval=10s --group nfs_group
pcs resource create nfs_mount Filesystem device=/dev/vg_nfs/lv_nfs directory=/data fstype=xfs --group nfs_group
pcs resource create nfs_volume nfsserver nfs_shared_infodir=/data nfs_ip=10.10.1.210 --group nfs_group
pcs resource create nfs_volume_exportfs exportfs clientspec=* options=rw,sync,no_root_squash directory=/data fsid=1 --group nfs_group
pcs resource create nfs_notify nfsnotify source_host=10.10.1.210 --group nfs_group

Current status
pcs status
Cluster name: ha_nfs
Cluster Summary:
  * Stack: corosync (Pacemaker is running)
  * Current DC: prod-nfs-2.corp.domain.local (version 2.1.8-1.el9-39ef08240) - partition with quorum
  * Last updated: Tue Aug 13 09:46:58 2024 on prod-nfs-1.corp.domain.local
  * Last change:  Tue Aug 13 09:42:20 2024 by hacluster via hacluster on prod-nfs-1.corp.domain.local
  * 2 nodes configured
  * 4 resource instances configured

Node List:
  * Online: [ prod-nfs-1.corp.domain.local prod-nfs-2.corp.domain.local ]

Full List of Resources:
  * Resource Group: nfs_group:
    * ClusterIP (ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2):         Started prod-nfs-2.corp.domain.local
    * nfs_mount (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem):      Started prod-nfs-2.corp.domain.local
    * nfs_volume        (ocf:heartbeat:nfsserver):       Started prod-nfs-2.corp.domain.local
    * nfs_volume_exportfs       (ocf:heartbeat:exportfs):        Started prod-nfs-2.corp.domain.local

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled

corosync status
Aug 13 09:48:39 notice  [MAIN  ] Corosync Cluster Engine 3.1.8 starting up
Aug 13 09:48:39 info    [MAIN  ] Corosync built-in features: dbus systemd xmlconf vqsim nozzle snmp pie relro bindnow

Current configuration
pcs config 
Cluster Name: ha_nfs
Corosync Nodes:
 prod-nfs-1.corp.runovo.ru prod-nfs-2.corp.runovo.ru
Pacemaker Nodes:
 prod-nfs-1.corp.runovo.ru prod-nfs-2.corp.runovo.ru

Resources:
  Group: nfs_group
    Resource: ClusterIP (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2)
      Attributes: ClusterIP-instance_attributes
        cidr_netmask=32
        ip=10.10.1.210
        nic=enp1s0
      Operations:
        monitor: ClusterIP-monitor-interval-10s
          interval=10s
        start: ClusterIP-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s timeout=20s
        stop: ClusterIP-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s timeout=20s
    Resource: nfs_mount (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=Filesystem)
      Attributes: nfs_mount-instance_attributes
        device=/dev/vg_nfs/lv_nfs
        directory=/data
        fstype=xfs
      Operations:
        monitor: nfs_mount-monitor-interval-20s
          interval=20s timeout=40s
        start: nfs_mount-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s timeout=60s
        stop: nfs_mount-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s timeout=60s
    Resource: nfs_volume (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=nfsserver)
      Attributes: nfs_volume-instance_attributes
        nfs_ip=10.10.1.210
        nfs_shared_infodir=/data
      Operations:
        monitor: nfs_volume-monitor-interval-10s
          interval=10s timeout=20s
        start: nfs_volume-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s timeout=40s
        stop: nfs_volume-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s timeout=20s
    Resource: nfs_volume_exportfs (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=exportfs)
      Attributes: nfs_volume_exportfs-instance_attributes
        clientspec=*
        directory=/data
        fsid=1
        options=rw,sync,no_root_squash
      Operations:
        monitor: nfs_volume_exportfs-monitor-interval-10s
          interval=10s timeout=20s
        start: nfs_volume_exportfs-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s timeout=40s
        stop: nfs_volume_exportfs-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s timeout=120s

Resources Defaults:
  Meta Attrs: build-resource-defaults
    resource-stickiness=1 (id: build-resource-stickiness)

Cluster Properties: cib-bootstrap-options
  cluster-infrastructure=corosync
  cluster-name=ha_nfs
  dc-version=2.1.8-1.el9-39ef08240
  have-watchdog=false
  last-lrm-refresh=1723517478
  stonith-enabled=false

The problem is the following.
As you can see above, prod-nfs-2.corp.runovo.ru is currently active.
Checking the contents of /data on prod-nfs-2
[root@prod-nfs-2 data]# ll /data
total 4
-rw-r-----  1 root    root    200 Aug 13 09:33 etab
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 09:11 export-lock
drwx------  2 root    root     25 Aug 13 09:33 nfsdcld
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 09:33 rmtab
dr-xr-xr-x 11 root    root      0 Aug 13 09:33 rpc_pipefs
drwxr-x--x  5 rpcuser rpcuser  56 Aug 13 09:33 statd
drwxr-x--x  2 root    root      6 Aug 13 09:33 v4recovery
-rw-r-----  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 09:33 xtab

I check the contents of /data on prod-nfs-1 and it is clear that the directory is empty
[root@prod-nfs-1 data]# ll /data
total 0

On prod-nfs-2 I create a file touch /data/some-file and check the contents
[root@prod-nfs-2 data]# ll /data
total 4
-rw-r-----  1 root    root    200 Aug 13 09:33 etab
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 09:11 export-lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 09:53 some-file
drwx------  2 root    root     25 Aug 13 09:33 nfsdcld
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 09:33 rmtab
dr-xr-xr-x 11 root    root      0 Aug 13 09:33 rpc_pipefs
drwxr-x--x  5 rpcuser rpcuser  56 Aug 13 09:33 statd
drwxr-x--x  2 root    root      6 Aug 13 09:33 v4recovery
-rw-r-----  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 09:33 xtab

Now I put prod-nfs-2 into standby mode and check /data
[root@prod-nfs-2 data]# ll /data
total 0

On prod-nfs-1 I check /data, but the file some-file did not appear
[root@prod-nfs-1 mkostromin]# ll /data
total 4
-rw-r-----  1 root    root    200 Aug 13 10:07 etab
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 07:39 export-lock
drwx------  2 root    root     25 Aug 13 10:07 nfsdcld
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 10:07 rmtab
dr-xr-xr-x 11 root    root      0 Aug 13 10:07 rpc_pipefs
drwxr-x--x  5 rpcuser rpcuser  56 Aug 13 07:39 statd
drwxr-x--x  2 root    root      6 Aug 13 07:39 v4recovery
-rw-r-----  1 root    root      0 Aug 13 07:39 xtab

Could you please tell me why synchronization does not occur and how to set it up?

As far as I can see you don't have anything set up or configured that either offers shared storage to both servers  (like direct attached shared storage, iSCSI or a SAN)  or replicates your data from one server or another, like for example DRBD - It looks like you only configure local disk storage and data stored on local disk in one server won't be available on the other with the set up you've described.
